# Deploy project with xUnit reference as NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, xunit

I have a library that contains some classes, which I need in several Unit Test projects. The library should be deployed as a NuGet package in my private repository. I already deployed some NuGet packages there, so I know what I have to do.

BUT: Inside of this library I need a reference to xUnit. And as soon as I add this reference, there is no more .nupkg file created when execute `dotnet pack`.

Another interesting effect is, that the project icon turns into a Unit Test icon as soon as I add xUnit:

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Class Library
2. Add a reference to the xUnit NuGet package
3. Right click the project and click on pack

Expected Behvior: there should be a .nupkg file in ./bin/Debug

Actual Behevior: there is no such file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to create Class Library project but don't add full `xunit` package, just:
`xunit.abstractions` and `xunit.assert` this way VS won't detect it as unit test project but you can still put some common code.

[image]

Comment: @timnot90, it's a more appropriate answer if we talk about some library for tests, I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

According to https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7539, some projects seem to be "not packable" by default. You have to enable this manually by adding the following lines to your .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After that, the .nupkg file is created expected.