# how to publish nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to publish NuGet package following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli).

when I run `dotnet pack`, I get this response

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Restore completed in 59.66 ms for
> /Users/ali/Desktop/earthlink/AutoCrud/AutoCrud.csproj.

while in the document I'm following the output should be this :

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Core
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Restore completed in 29.91 ms for
> D:\proj\AppLoggerNet\AppLogger\AppLogger.csproj.   AppLogger ->
> D:\proj\AppLoggerNet\AppLogger\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\AppLogger.dll
> Successfully created package
> 'D:\proj\AppLoggerNet\AppLogger\bin\Debug\AppLogger.1.0.0.nupkg'.

as you can see, in my case no `.nupkg` file created.

here is my `.csproj` file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <PackageId>AutoCrud</PackageId>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <Authors>Ali Faris</Authors>
        <Company>Ali Faris</Company>
        <PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
        <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/alicompiler/AutoCrud.NetCore</RepositoryUrl>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="3.1.7"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.14.5"/>
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

how could I generate this `.nupkg` file.

by the way, I'm using macOS

Comment: I normally edit the csproj file with notepad to prevent issues like this.  Visual Studio adds object to project using full path names.  When I have a VS project that references other projects I like to use relative path names.  You are getting an error because one of you paths is contain D:\  which is not on the machine.

Comment: I'm using macOS with Rider as my editor. I'm not getting any error, the issue I'm having is that `.nuget` file is not generated when I run `dotnet pack`

Comment: If you use `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` it should be generated when using `dotnet build` no pack needed.

Comment: Do a search in output folder *.* and sort by time and see what latest file that was created.  Open any log files to see if additional debug info is in any files.

Comment: @MaximilianAst I just tried `dotnet build` only `AutoCrud.dll` , no `.nupkg` file created.

Comment: @jdweng I did a search, but no `.nupkg` file found

Comment: the nupkg will be in `bin/Release/name.nupkg` or `bin/Debug/name.nupkg` but not in that  `bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1` subfolder

Comment: As a reference, I once created a github repo to create a minimal package and upload it (in `.github/workflows/dotnet-core.yml` will be the build script):
https://github.com/MaximilianAst/GithubActionsToNuGetTest

Comment: did you check log files.  What was last file(s) created

Comment: the issue seems to be related to the dependencies that I'm having when I remove the dependencies everything works file. but when I include the dependencies the issue appears.
still trying to figure out a solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144739/5136659)

The issue seemed to be related to some dependencies, in particular: `xunit` and `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, these dependencies are "not packable".

the solution was by adding `<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>` to PropertyGroup

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
     ...
</PropertyGroup>
```